# Make list undraggable on button click Sortable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, rubaxa-sortable

I am using this plugin:

https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

I want to make the list undraggable when the user clicks the button. From the github page, it seems that I can use `disable:true`to do so but how do I make it work on button click?

I have tried:

```
Sortable.create(simpleList, {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        disable: true,
    })
});
```

But it makes the undraggable to begin with.

Non-working Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/880auLx8/

Working Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/880auLx8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with the instructions in the readme, you should get something along the lines of:

```
var sortable = Sortable.create(simpleList, {});
$("#button").click(function () {
    sortable.option("disabled", true);
});
```